# At Electron, How to resolve Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown on(event: 'ready', listener: (launchInfo: unknown) => void): this;

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, electron

```
An error occurs when npm run build.
Electron: 7.1.2
The typescript is ^2.5.1
The target is ES2017.
```

The error details are as below.

When I did at 
these conditions

```
Electron: 6.0.0
The typescript is ^2.5.1
The target is ES2017.
```

the below errors did not occur. But I change Electron version as 7.1.2, these errors occur.

Can you tell me why it does not build?

```
> tsc
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:171:62 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
171 userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:180:62 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
180 userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:189:62 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
189 userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:198:62 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
198 userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:309:57 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
309                                               userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:318:57 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
318                                               userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:327:57 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
327                                               userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:336:57 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
336                                               userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:507:47 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
507     on(event: 'ready', listener: (launchInfo: unknown) => void): this;
 
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:508:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
508     once(event: 'ready', listener: (launchInfo: unknown) => void): this;
   
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:509:56 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
509     addListener(event: 'ready', listener: (launchInfo: unknown) => void): this;
          
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:510:59 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
510     removeListener(event: 'ready', listener: (launchInfo: unknown) => void): this;
             
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:722:61 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
722 userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:731:61 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
731 userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:740:61 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
740 userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:749:61 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
749 userInfo: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:935:57 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
935     getGPUInfo(infoType: 'basic' | 'complete'): Promise;
           
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:3637:45 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
3637                                     params: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:3647:45 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
3647                                     params: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:3657:45 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
3657                                     params: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:3667:45 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
3667                                     params: unknown) => void): this;
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:6928:98 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
6928     subscribeLocalNotification(event: string, callback: (event: string, userInfo: Record, object: string) => void): number;
     
   
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:6951:93 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
6951     subscribeNotification(event: string, callback: (event: string, userInfo: Record, object: string) => void): number;
                                
node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:6959:102 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown
6959     subscribeWorkspaceNotification(event: string, callback: (event: string, userInfo: Record, object: string) => void): void;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your typescript to version 3 or above.

In your application

```
npm install typescript@latest --save
```

or install it as global,

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```